# Camera Intrinsic Matrix is very different from manufacturer's specification

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm new in camera calibration and I'm currently working on a task to find the direction of a Laser Rangefinder with an IR camera. I'm using OpenCV with Python to do that. For some specific reason, I have to capture at a distance larger than 50m.

Specification of my camera is Resolution: 640x480, pixel pitch: 12x12 micro-mets, and focal length 75mm.

When I capture a lot of pictures at different poses and use `calibrateCameraExtended`, it returns to me this intrinsic matrix:

```
[[5.63826892e+03 0.00000000e+00 2.39401413e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 4.46636598e+03 3.17556975e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
```

The principle point is quite accurate but the focal length is very difference. It must be fx=fy=6250 or near this. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob


# Defining the dimensions of checkerboard
CHECKERBOARD = (6, 6)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# Creating vector to store vectors of 3D points for each checkerboard image
objpoints = []
# Creating vector to store vectors of 2D points for each checkerboard image
imgpoints = []

# Defining the world coordinates for 3D points
objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0] * CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0, :, :2] = (
    np.mgrid[0 : CHECKERBOARD[0], 0 : CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2) * 130
)
prev_img_shape = None

# Extracting path of individual image stored in a given directory
images = glob.glob("./filterImages/*.jpg")
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    # If desired number of corners are found in the image then ret = true

    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(
        gray,
        CHECKERBOARD,
        cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH
        + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK
        + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE,
    )
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        # refining pixel coordinates for given 2d points.
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, CHECKERBOARD, corners2, ret)

    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()

h, w = img.shape[:2]

(
    ret,
    mtx,
    dist,
    rvecs,
    tvecs,
    stdDeviationsIntrinsics,
    stdDeviationsExtrinsics,
    perViewErrors,
) = cv2.calibrateCameraExtended(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[:2], None, None)

rMatrices = []

for rvec in rvecs:
    dst, jacobian = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)
    rMatrices.append(dst)

# relativePositon(rMatrices, tvecs, distanceVecs)

print("Camera matrix : \n")
print(mtx)
# print("dist : \n")
# print(dist)
# print("rvecs : \n")
# print(rvecs)
print("tvecs : \n")
print(tvecs)
# print("perViewErrors : \n")
# print(perViewErrors)
```

My repo is [here](https://github.com/feederndt/cameraCalibration).